# why negative cycle exists if we can relax the edges one more time after running the Bellman Ford Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford

We know Bellman Ford is an algorithm to find the negative cycle. 
And here is the algorithm for Bellman Ford
Input: Given a graph G(V,E) and w(e) is weight
Output: Return Yes if negative cycle exists.

```
1: set d(s) = 0 and d(v) = 1 for all v (- s
2: for i = 1 ... n-1 do
3:      for every edge (u, v) in G do
4:        if d(v) > d(u) + w(u,v) then
5:           d(v) = d(u) + w(u,v)
6:      end for
7: end for
8: for every edge (u, v) in G do
9:     if d(v) > d(u) + w(u, v) then
10:       return True
11:return False
```

Line 8 - Line 11 is the doing one more relax to detect the negative cycle, but why these lines guarantee detect the negative cycle if have one in the graph?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graph theory. Try asking on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know Bellman Ford as an algorithm to find the shortest path in an network that may have negative edge weights. Finding negative cylces might be an extension,

Answer (score 0):

You are detecting the fact that the shortest path between some pair of vertices is so long that it must be visiting some vertex more than once, so it contains a cycle. If that cycle is of length >= 0 then removing it would at most keep the length of the path the same, so it would not be found as an improvement. Therefore if you find such a shortest path with a cycle in it the cycle must be of negative length. Also, if there is a cycle of negative length it will be found as a shortest path from any vertex in it back to that same vertex.